# Go to last file with rails.vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

I am just getting into rails.vim as my ROR IDE and I am really liking it. The only thing I don't know how to do, that I wish I could, is hop back to the last file I was editing.

For example, if I am editing one file, say a view and I use `:Rcontroller` to hop over the the corresponding controller, is there a way to quickly go back to the model (without `:Rmodel`)? I'm looking for some functionality like that of `CTRL-TAB` in visual studio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't actually related to Rails.vim plugin. Add the following line to your `.vimrc` file

```
map <Leader>p <C-^> " Go to previous file
```

Assuming `<Leader>` is mapped to `,` then you can just press `,p` to go to the previous file.

This is how I've mapped my leader:

```
let mapleader = ","
```

Answer (score 2):

To go back just hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> in command mode, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to go forward in opened file history.